# How to install sun-java6-jdk on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, sun-java6-jdk

I am having a problem to install sun-java6-jdk on Ubuntu 10.04.

I googled and tried all but none of them worked.

When I type

```
apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

, I get the following message.

> Reading package lists...Done Building
>   state information ...Done Package
>   sun-java6-jdk is not available, but is
>   referred to by another package. This
>   may mean that the package is missing,
>   has been obsoleted , or is only
>   available from another source. E:
>   Package sun-java6-jdk has no
>   installation candidate.

Could anyone tell me how to install sun-java6-jdk on Ubuntu 10.04 please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try updating apt by issuning the command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then try the installation of sun-java6-jdk again.

Comment: Thanks. After that I used sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk then it is installed now.